# Redirect URI in case of WebAuthenticationBroker for authentication of Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am developing an windows store app in which I desired to provide authentication to users through **Yammer**. 
I am using WebAuthenticationBroker for the same as Windows Azure service doesnot support Yammer authentication.

On referring http://developer.yammer.com/introduction/ , I found that  my app needs to redirect to the following url on the click of sign in button:

> https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=**[:client_id]**&redirect_uri=**[:redirect_uri]**

I am using the following code to achieve the above functionality:

```
Uri sid = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
string loginURI = "https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=28qx6kPAmf4HfUFhwU7WWA&redirect_uri=" + sid ;
```

I get the pop up , but the windows does not redirect me with a valid code.
I am not sure what should the redirect_uri be in order to redirect the code to my app. 
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Understand that you want to have this redirect back to your application.  What url are you using for the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit the redirect URL in app registration page. Then call web authentication broker like this.

```
var webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.UseTitle,
        new Uri("https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[:client_id]&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri]"),
        new Uri("http://[:redirect_uri]"));
```

[:redirect_uri] can be anything you want, like google.com. If user allows your app to access Yammer, you will get auth code via redirect URL.

```
http://[:redirect_uri]?code=[:code]
```

If user denies authorization, you will get error like this.

```
http://[:redirect_uri]?error=[:error]&error_description=[:error_description]
```

If you get auth code successfully, you need request for access token by sending HTTP POST request.

```
https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id=[:client_id]&client_secret=[:client_secret]&code=[:code]
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply. I tried using google.com in redirect uri , but it then redirects me to google.com , I dont want that to open in my app.
I am able to retrieve the code in the format mentioned.
However I want the redirect_uri as such that it should redirect back to **my app** and I get the uri.

Comment: Then try to use the Client-side flow from [here](http://developer.yammer.com/authentication/)

Comment: I am still unable to use redirect_url ... please help